# 403 Forbidden for /home/my-username/Dropbox/Hemsidor as directory root

Tags: apache2

I'm trying setup Apache to point the directory root to `/home/my-username/Dropbox/Hemsidor` but when I go to localhost I got `403 Forbidden`. I don't have any .htaccess file in the home directory (`Hemsidor`) so I don't know what the problem is. I have tested to add `Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in my httpd.conf file and then restarted Apache but with no luck.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the user and group of the directory as `www-data` via `chown` and `chgrp` command

Comment: How do I do this? I'm completely new to configuring LAMP in Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo chown www-data /home/my-username/Dropbox/Hemsidor && sudo chgrp www-data /home/my-username/Dropbox/Hemsidor

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I'm still getting `403 Forbidden` even when I have restarted Apache after entering those commands. By the way! Nothing happened when I entered those commands. Is that right?